# Hardware/software serial for HC-05

Tags: serial, hardware, uart, hc-05, software

can anyone please tell me the whole difference between hardware and software serial for the HC-05.
I read UART,USB cable, serial and I was like really confused
so what is the difference and advantages between both?
thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Hardware vs Software Serial:** Most microcontrollers/Arduinos have at least 1 hardware Serial interface. That means, that for this Serial interface the actual communication protocol (the transmission and receiving of the actual data) is implemented in dedicated hardware inside the microcontroller (which also means there are fixed pins, where you can connect to them on the board). That way you don't need code for doing the complex communication protocol. Instead the main CPU is only involved to handle the received and to-be-transmitted data, which need to be placed in a buffer register. The dedicated hardware then automatically sends and received the data.

  As the number of hardware Serial interfaces is limited and fixed for the Arduino board/microcontroller, it happens, that you need more Serial interfaces, than you have in hardware on your board/in your microcontroller. Then you can use `SoftwareSerial`. That is a library, which handles the complete communication protocol in software, by directly setting and reading the electrical pin states according to the protocol. The advantage is, that you can use this on any digital pins for such an interface. Disadvantage is, that doing such things in software is complex. You can only listen on 1 `SoftwareSerial` interface at a time and the baudrate is limited (depending on the actual used microcontroller, e.g. it's frequency).
- **UART vs Serial:** UART is the technical term for the used communication interface. `Serial` is an Arduino term, which is not used that way in other contexts. The real interface type is UART and the Arduino framework just names that `Serial` to make it simpler.
- **Connecting over USB cable or pins:** Let's take the Arduino Uno as example. It has 1 hardware serial interface. This interface is connected to the pins 0 and 1 (RX and TX), but also internally to an extra chip. That chip handles the USB connection and behaves as a USB-Serial bridge. When communicating with the Serial Monitor in the Arduino IDE, you are actually using this USB-Serial bridge to talk to the microcontroller on the Arduino. But you could also use the RX/TX pins to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware serial uses pins 0/1 on the Uno. You can't change those pins. Those pins are also the pins that are used to communicate with your computer. You can use hardware serial on those pins to communicate with the HC-05 *only* if you don't want to communicate with your computer.

SoftwareSerial can be used on any pins so can be used at the same time as the hardware serial for communicating with your computer. However SoftwareSerial is somewhat limited in what it can do.

Bigger boards (such as the Mega) usually have more than one hardware serial port. These are connected to the TX1/RX1, TX2/RX2 etc pins. These are the preferred method of connecting to external serial devices since they work more reliably that SoftwareSerial and concurrently with the computer's USB connection.